# Get the immediate container for the element in it?

Tags: python-3.x, list, iterable

Let's say I have a list :

```
l = ['x', [[1, [2, 3], 4]], 'y']
my_container = l[1]
my_ele = my_container[0]
```

In the situation I'm in, both 'my_container' & 'my_ele' are iterables, I know 'l' and 'my_ele' both exist, but I don't know directly that 'my_ele' is within a 'my_container'.

So is there a way to get to know about this 'my_container' without traversing the nested list 'l' recursively?

Comment: Maybe You can figure this out by looking/working in https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: @DanielHao Nice might help

Comment: A list like `my_container` can be contained in many parent lists. Perhaps it would be better to step back and have you explain the larger task. Why do you want to know if my_ele is in my_container via something like print(my_ele in my_container)